# Nodejs Cors issue Nodejs and React (production)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, setup-deployment

I have an issue getting requests from the browser and it is getting annoying!
Any hints are highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

I have nodejs setup as follows:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*",
    methods: "GET,POST",
    allowedHeaders: "Content-Type,Authorization",
    credentials: true,
    preflightContinue: true,
  })
);
app.use(express.json());
....
```

in Reacr Axios requests as follow

```
const getComments = () => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    method: "GET",
    url: `${url}/all`,
    withCredentials: true,
    crossorigin: true,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  };
  return axios(config)
    .then(serviceHelper.onGlobalSuccess)
    .catch(serviceHelper.onGlobalError);
};
```

[Cors Error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsCra.png)

Comment: can you show the route your are trying to get from & the value of ${url} I had similar issues once and it was due to a typo not actually cors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Authorization"
```

tells the server to allow only these headers. If you look into your request, you have this header.

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
```

This will be included in the header while making a request. This is getting rejected by the server.

Instead of that, try this

```
const getComments = () => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",

    },
    method: "GET",
    url: `${url}/all`,
    withCredentials: true,
  };
  return axios(config)
    .then(serviceHelper.onGlobalSuccess)
    .catch(serviceHelper.onGlobalError);
};
```

regards,
Jay

Comment: Man Thank you! I couldn't image cross origin is the problem :).

Comment: if this helps then you can accept my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hi jayakarthikeyan! Sorry I just did! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in your nodejs code

```
const express = require('express');
let server = express();
server.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept'
  );
  next();
});
```

Comment: Hi Bhagyashri , Thank you so much! I have tried this approach earlier, apparently as 
Jayakarthikeyan mentioned all I had to do is to delete the cross origin in Axios call  \_(ツ)_/¯ and it is working now!